# WebStorm to serve on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost

Tags: webstorm

When I press browser icon in the upper right corner in the IDE it opens it in the browser in localhost address. All I am doing is using my computers IP with same port as in IDE but it doesn't opens in my smartphone.

Comment: 1) So you are expecting to see an answer to your question within few minutes? Some questions may stay unanswered for days and then get great answer... 2) If you are using built-in web server (most likely) then you have to allow external connection in `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger --> Can accept external connections` and restart IDE. That's the only option I'm aware (and people are using it) 3) You can use your own web server then just define correct URL to be used in Deployment .. and that URL will be used instead of built-in server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since i'm not getting any answer for this question i think jetbrains do not provide support for this. Currently what i'm using is python SimpleHTTPServer i go into the project directory and run this simple command in the terminal
**python -m SimpleHTTPServer** and this does the job for me.